# On Submit Form Pass to and Run PHP Function

Tags: php

Lets say i have a html form as such below:

```
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And i have a PHP Function below

```
<?php
function show()
{
   $firstName= (What i submitted on form)
   $lastName= (What i submitted on form)
   echo "First Name: $firstName<br>";
   echo "Last Name: $lastName<br>";
}
?>
```

How can i make it so that when i press submit that it passes the information submitted to the php function `show()` and runs it?

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that you couldn't have Google Searched this problem.  You are after $_POST and $_GET.  Google search "Submitting data in PHP".

Comment: [THE PHP MANUAL On Form Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) **Read it**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `method` and `action` attributes on your **form**, i.e.:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then on `PHP` use `$_POST` to retrieve the values, i.e.:

**form.php**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['firstname']) and !empty($_POST['lastName'])){
       $firstName= $_POST['firstname'];
       $lastName= $_POST['lastName'];
       echo "First Name: $firstName<br>";
       echo "Last Name: $lastName<br>";
}  
?>
```

Comment: Of course, you should use AJAX, to submit forms, in most real world practices.

Comment: I agree, I normally use http://jqueryvalidation.org and ajax, but I guess this OP needed a basic explanation how a form works.